# How to improve this rails spec suite? (profiling given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Rails 3.2.16 project running ruby 1.9.3. I've profiled the test suite, and started with this numbers:

```
5531  31.0%  31.0%     5537  31.0% SQLite3::Statement#step
3099  17.4%  48.3%     3099  17.4% garbage_collector
2294  12.9%  61.2%     2294  12.9% BCrypt::Engine.__bc_crypt
2042  11.4%  72.6%     2042  11.4% IO.select
```

So I've read about GC tweaking (http://labs.clio.com/tuning-ruby-garbage-collection-for-rspec/) and got this numbers:

```
5649  36.6%  36.6%     5655  36.7% sqlite3::statement#step
2284  14.8%  51.4%     2284  14.8% bcrypt::engine.__bc_crypt
2039  13.2%  64.6%     2039  13.2% io.select
```

Now the culprit is bcrypt.. solution here (http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2012/11/12/tests-oddly-slow-might-be-bcrypt/). Now I have:

```
5971  42.7%  42.7%     5978  42.7% SQLite3::Statement#step
2058  14.7%  57.4%     2058  14.7% IO.select
 724   5.2%  62.5%      724   5.2% garbage_collector
```

Much better overall.. but I want more!

¿There is something to be done about SQLite3::Statement#step or IO.select ?